# Cannot find the file

Tags: android, android-file

I'm experiencing some trouble to open a file. well i've already used absolute path to know where the file is but it still cant open the file (file not found)

```
    public void ReadFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
       /** Read the contents of the given file. */


         String SourceID = new String();
         String LogicalID = new String();

         File fileDir = getFilesDir();
         String s = new String();

         s+=fileDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/Nodes.txt";
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(s));


         try 
         { 
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())  
            { 

                SourceID = scanner.nextLine();  
                LogicalID = scanner.nextLine();  
                String ss = new String();
                ss+="    ----------------> "+SourceID+" "+LogicalID+"   ";

                Log.v(TAG, ss);
                ListaNodesSTART.add(new NodesToStart(SourceID,LogicalID));
            } 
         }catch(Exception ee){//Log.v(TAG, "Could not read the file");  
             ERROR.setText("Could Not Read file Nodes.txt");
         ErRorLog.setText("Could Not Read file Nodes.txt");}

         finally{scanner.close(); }
     }
```

I guess the problem is that the device hasn't the file, but, how can i upload it when the app starts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you gave this permission in your manifest.xml uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: yes i gave but it hasnt found it anyway:
06-04 16:50:36.674: W/System.err(24897): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/neves.ProjectNodes/files/Nodes.txt (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have NO file in the device! To work with static files, insert them in your assets folder and then:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = null;
try {
    files = assetManager.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
}
for(String filename : files) { 
    if( filename.equals("Nodes.txt") {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            // Do your work with file
            in = assetManager.open(filename);
            // ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked man ;) thanks a lot.. One more thing.. Sorry im a noob.. :-/ hod can i close a thread here?  sorry about this silly question

Comment: It is better to close InputStream but there is no thread here! If this works for you, please do not forget to accept this as answer to help other people find the right solution!

Comment: Yes i know, but i was talking about the thread in the forum. I've already see some closed. Thats why i was wondering if i must do the same and how

Comment: Well it never reaches the line  InputStream in = null;
 because it never passes the condition if( filename.equals("Nodes.txt").. but it gives me no errors

Comment: Copy your Nodes.txt file in your assets folder and rebuild entire project.